Identifying maximum illumination, calculus problem.
Note: THE QUESTION HAS BEEN ANSWERED! I will not close the poll, incase someone identifies an error in the answer written below or finds a better way to solve it.
I am working on a problem.
The question is, "A light source is to be placed directly above the center of a circular table of radius 1:5 m. The illumination
at any point on the table is directly proportional to the sine of the angle between the table and the line
joining the source and the point and inversely proportional to the square of the distance from the source.
Find the height above the circle at which illumination on the edge of the table is maximized."
I seem to be getting the answer as 0. However, this doesn't make sense. The book states the answer is, 1.060660172m.
I am really new to calculus, so I know I might be wrong.
Have you figured out the solution? Let me know. {Solution already found!}

How did you get $0$?

I simply found d (distance).
Then found I(h) = (1.5/root(h^2+2.25))/(h^2+2.25).
Then I found the derivative, and set it to zero, resulting in h=0.
I believe I am missing something, could you help me?

That seems too succinct. Besides, adding that as a comment carries no weight. You should edit your question instead.

Oh okay, let me edit the question to show my working. Thanks for telling me.

Here's a picture I drew that helps to visualize this:

In my post, I'll use $h$ for height and $d$ for distance.
The problem says that the illumination at the edge of the table is directly proportional to the sine of the angle $\theta$, and we can easily figure that out from the labeling in the picture:
$\sin(\theta)=\frac{h}{d}$
By using the Pythagorean Theorem, we can also rewrite the distance in terms of height:
$d=\sqrt{h^2+1.5^2}$
So then, we have:
$\underline{\sin(\theta)=\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+2.25}}}$
Next, the problem says that the illumination is inversely proportional to the square of the distance between the light source and the point on the table. We can first write the square of the distance:
$d^2=h^2+2.25$
The term "inversely proportional" is just a concise way to say "proportional to the reciprocal" of the stated term. From this, our term becomes $\left(\frac{1}{h^2+2.25}\right)$. Now we can write the full equation for the illumination $(I)$ at the edge of the table:
$\underline{I=\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+2.25}}\times \frac{1}{h^2+2.25}}$
In order to find the location of the maximum value of this function, we need to differentiate it with respect to height (since the height is our independent variable), then find the root where the derivative changes from positive to negative. By inspection, we can tell that the derivative equation for $I$ would be pretty messy and difficult to work with as it is. So we should first try to condense $I$ and remove the radicals if possible:
$$I=\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+2.25}}\times \frac{1}{h^2+2.25}$$
$$I=\frac{h}{\left( h^2+2.25 \right)^{\frac32}}$$
Now we differentiate this (I didn't include the calculations, but it's done using the quotient rule):
$$\frac{dI}{dh}=\frac{(h^2+2.25)^{\frac32}-3h^2(h^2+2.25)^{\frac12}}{(h^2+2.25)^3}$$
To find the roots, we need to set the numerator equal to zero and solve for $h$:
$(h^2+2.25)^{\frac32}-3h^2(h^2+2.25)^{\frac12}=0$
I actually didn't know how to proceed from here, but ChatGPT gave me a great idea: use the substitution $s=(h^2+2.25)^{\frac12}$. This would condense the equation into a much more manageable form:
$$(h^2+2.25)^{\frac32}-3h^2(h^2+2.25)^{\frac12}=0$$
$$s^3-3h^2s=0$$
$$s(s^2-3h^2)=0$$
This could have two ways of being solved: $s=0$ and $s^2-3h^2=0$. Let's try both ways:
$$s=0$$
$$(h^2+2.25)^{\frac12}=0$$
$$h^2+2.25=0$$
$$h^2=-2.25$$
As you can see, this is impossible to solve because a square of a number can never be negative. Since we found $s=0$ to be invalid, we can move on to the next solution:
$$s^2-3h^2=0$$
$$h^2+2.25-3h^2=0$$
$$-2h^2=-2.25$$
$$h^2=\frac{2.25}{2}$$
$$\boxed{h=\pm\frac{1.5}{\sqrt{2}}}$$
Here, we have two solutions from the square root. It is safe to dismiss the negative solution since that would imply that the light source is underneath the table (negative height), which would be strange. Therefore, the height of the light source is $\frac{1.5}{\sqrt{2}}$ meters above the table surface, which approximates to $1.060660172$ meters.

Okay, I get it! Thank you so much! I believe I was making a mistake while solving for 0. I approached the answer with your method as well (I believe sketching a diagram for visual is great). Also, the idea of replacing the value with s was genius. Thanks a lot!

Glad this helped :)

As the lumen law states
$$
i(r,h) = k \frac{\frac{h}{\sqrt{r^2+h^2}}}{r^2+h^2}
$$
so
$$
\frac{di}{dh} = \frac{r^2-2 h^2}{\left(h^2+r^2\right)^{5/2}}
$$
$i$ has a maximum at $h = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$ so at $r = 1.5$ we have
$$
h_{max} = 1.06066 
$$
This gives maximum illumination at the table border.
NOTE
$$
\frac{d^2i}{dh^2} = (6 h^3 - 9 h r^2)/(h^2 + r^2)^{7/2}
$$
and at $h = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$ we have $\frac{d^2i}{dh^2} = -\frac{16 r^3}{9 \sqrt{3} \left(r^2\right)^{7/2}}< 0$
